# Backing different prop type in .NET, EF with C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I tried to do the following:

`Product` model:

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    private string _PictureUrls;

    [NotMapped]
    public string[] PictureUrls
    {
        get { return _PictureUrls.Split(','); }
        set { _PictureUrls = string.Join(',', value); }
    }
}
```

and:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder
      .Entity<Product>()
      .Property(props => props.PictureUrls)
      .HasField("_PictureUrls")
      .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.PreferFieldDuringConstruction);
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> The specified field '_PictureUrls' of type 'string' cannot be used for the property 'Product.PictureUrls' of type 'string[]'. Only backing fields of types that are compatible with the property type can be used.

I understand why, but can't figure out how to solve this, help please.

Comment: why isn't picture urls its own table?

Comment: i thought about that, but i dont want to, im kinda just want to store "Array of strings(URLs)", but still to reference it as an array

Comment: You might be able to use [ValueConverters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations) to achieve what you want, but you should be aware that this is a bit of an antipattern and won't scale well at all, and will make some queries extremely inefficient if not impossible.

Comment: ok then, maybe u right, so i should create a Pictures table for example, and each one should have id, url, productId related? then in the product model, how to archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do consider making PictureUrl an entity, but what you're attempting will work.

The string needs to be a shadow property of string type, not mapped to the array property.  eg

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .Property(typeof(string), "_PictureUrls")
                .HasField("_PictureUrls")
                .HasColumnName("PictureUrls")
                .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.PreferFieldDuringConstruction);
```